# sums up the values of all factorials using recursion

Tags: java, recursion, sum, factorial

---

I try to write a recursive method that sums up the values of all factorials from 0 to input number and returns the result as a double.
I use 
 recursive factorial method to calculate the individual factorials.
 but I do not understand how I can make the method that sum all factorials
recursive method to use two recursion instead of one recursion and for loop.

This is the code!

```
public static int factorial(int numberinput) {
    if (numberinput == 0)
        return 1;
    else 
        return (numberinput*factorial(numberinput-1));
}

public static double sum(int numberinput) {
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= numberinput; i++)
        sum += factorial(i);
    return sum ;      
}
```

Comment: one possibility would be to add a `runningTotal` argument to your factorial method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recursive `sum` method can behave exactly as your recursive `factorial` method. The only difference is that it uses addition instead of multiplication.

```
public static double sum(int numberinput) {
    if (numberinput == 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return factorial(numberinput) + sum(numberinput-1);
}
```

Comment: 0! = 1, so the if statement should return 1 instead of 0

Comment: @Genzotto I didn't think about that. You are correct. I'll fix it. Thanks